# Sharepoint 2010 Foundation - Provisioning a page based on a different master page

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I was able to [add a new master page to Sharepoint](http://pramodaachi.blog.com/2011/05/19/creating-a-page-layout-in-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-studio-2010/) 2010 Foundation.

I can see that page in my master page library. However, when I try to provision a new page, I don't have any option to pick this master page. Is there a step mission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This step isn't available in SharePoint Foundation. You are able to set a custom masterpage by the object model and I guess also with SharePoint Designer.